# [VB.NET]abort code/task after a time

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Can i set time limit for a task or a code? for example if i want to show message boxes for 10 seconds and then stop or change the the message body ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out timers.  There are three different kinds of timers:

- [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)
- [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)
- [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

Which one will work best for you will depend entirely on your specific situation.  Given the limited information you provided, I suspect that the easiest way to do what you need to do is to create your own message-box-like form and place a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` component on the form (you can find it in the form designer's tool box).  Have the form start the timer in its own `Shown` event.  And then show the form using the `ShowDialog` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.thread.aspx%5d) and abort it when you want:

```
Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf MyMethod)
t1.Start()
Timer1.Start()

Private Sub MyMethod()
    ' Do what you want
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    t1.Abort() 
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok , how can i enable a timer using it for 120 seconds and then disable it ? = timer1.start(for 120 seconds) , after 120secons(timer1.stop)

Comment: @user1970090 `Timer1.Interval = 120000` (milliseconds) before it starts